# AC constant current (6 A rms) to 12 V DC

Tags: led, led-strip, constant-current, led-driver

How to convert AC Constant current 6 A rms to 12 V DC (or 24 V DC) ? 
I want this circuit for LED power supply.
In addition the circuit has 2 steps to control illumination of LEDs.

Comment: What application do you need to use a current source (that is not DC) and use that to generate a voltage?

Comment: XY problem me thinks... Question is way too short to guess an answer.

Comment: Can you give us exact details of the power supply? A clear photo of its label would be good.

Comment: What's the problem?  Buy a CC LED driver from Mean Well.

Answer (score 3):

It is extremely unlikely that you have a CC AC source available.

More likely is that your LED string needs a maximum of 12 or 24 V DC for full brightness, and **you need to figure this out before you can effectively ask for a solution.**

For example, most LED strings are 12 V DC. The current required varies with the number of LEDs.
These can be driven in several different ways:

1. A DC power supply providing a regulated (but adjustable) supply of around 12 V. Altering the supply voltage alters the brightness.
2. A Constant current LED power supply. Here you control the current through the LED string and typically don't turn the LEDs ON/OFF at a high rate. This is the type of driver used in LCD TVs for example.
3. A simple regulated power supply followed by a PWM switch. Here the ratio of ON/OFF times sets the brightness of the string.

Comment: well, i have six ,12 V DC, 10 W LED strips and my power supply is 6 A rms from constant current regulator (CCR). How to convert AC constant current to DC voltage ? how to connect LED strips (series or parallel ) ?

Comment: Post a link or picture of your power supply (the label) ....what makes you think it's a CC regulator

Comment: 6.3 A or sometimes 6.6 A constant current AC supplies are used for airport runway lights. High level of redundancy but very specialized drivers for all non-incandescent lamps. My old teacher made fluorescent tube drivers for said constant current loops.

Comment: @winny ....sure, but they were DC power supplies with a CC output ....not CC AC.

Comment: No, I'm dead certain it's AC. They use current transformers to tap off the CC primary line and you can inject as much voltage drop as you need power on your secondary. I'll see if I can dig up a link.

Comment: @JackCreasey  I am also sure that winny is right. In the past these circuits were fed from automated variac controlled CC output units. The idea is to realise a fail save serial lamp connection circuit. A failing lamp changes the voltage to maintain the CC output

Comment: I've seen servo driven current controllers .....but that's not what the OP described.

Comment: bad assumption that OP does not have an AC CC supply. These are standard in airfield LED lighting.

Comment: @hassan789, those are AC driven DC constant current drivers ...NOT constant current AC which is a different beast altogether.

Comment: @decapod  ….a servo driven variac produces a variable voltage ….used in all sorts of primitive regulation systems. They change the voltage (and by implication could be driven by a current sensor)  ...but do NOT provide constant current.

Comment: @JackCreasey. You are mistaken; FAA CCRs produce 6.6A rms (AC current). I worked as a design engineer in the airfeild lighting industry. Here is a spec https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150_5345_10g.doc

Comment: @hassan789 You are apparently correct, that looks like a ferro- resonant regulator. However ...what has this to do with the OPs question ….48W as opposed to the kW ratings of the landing light regulator.

Comment: @JackCreasey the CCRs power hundereds of lights using isolation transformers. The circuit is a series circuit (like christmas tree lights)

Comment: @hassan789 Connected as a series seems to be just the wrong way to do it. Any failure would result in the loss of the whole string of lights.

Comment: @JackCreasey Like I said, isolation transformers are used. in case a unit fails, the secondary is shorted. eg: http://www.dyne.com.au/images/electrical-specification.jpg

Comment: @Jack: CC is used for runway lighting as there is no issue with voltage drop along the runway.

Answer (score 0):

Only the principle. A complete workout requires much more.

If the CC chain must be failproof you need a current transformer otherwise you can place a bridge rectifier directly into the chain for a constant LED load. Split the LEDS into 2 sets using only one set for low illumination and 2 sets for high illumination.

The second LED set to be switched on or off depending on the incomming current or voltage. This depends on the measuring point.

If PWM is to be used the world becomes more complex but not impossible